# Where should I do my kendo widget garbage cleanup?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

How/where do I properly cleanup kendo widgets? I don't want to keep stacking up instances obviously, but I'm having trouble deciding what events to bind my `.destroy()` to. Telerik's documentation doesn't really talk about this very much.

I'm creating multiple instances of touch widgets (for dynamic list data) to handle listview swipes for each `li` element and I want to clean them up when I navigate.

Is there an easy way to just clean up all widgets associated with a listview (touch/switches)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kendo Mobile, the first time your view is navigated to, it is initialized and the elements added to the DOM. However, when you navigate away from a view, it remains completely in memory and attached to the DOM, but gets hidden by the view navigated to. This means there usually isn't a case where you need to destroy your widgets and event handlers.

However, you can destroy the items in your view when the [view.hide](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/mobile/ui/view#events-hide) event is called.

If you want an easier way to destroy all the widgets under a particular element, you can use [kendo.destroy()](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo#methods-destroy) and pass in the element.

If you are using any MVVM in the items you are trying to destroy, I would recommend also calling [kendo.unbind()](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo#methods-unbind) first.

Something like:

```
var $listView = $("#listView:);
kendo.unbind($listView);
kendo.destroy($listView);
```

Note that this code would destroy the listview widget as well as any widgets in each `li` element.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification with this. I'm only thinking of doing this with regards to child list elements that get new data each time the view is navigated to. Do I not need to worry about this? If I look at my KendoUI Console widget list, my buttons/switches/touch widgets just keep adding up every time I load a new list's worth of data...

Comment: That is interesting. How does your data get refreshed when the view is navigated to? Is the ListView bound to a DataSource? I thought the ListView widget would clean up its own child elements, but... maybe not?

Comment: Hmm, You may be on to something. One of my listviews in question is bound to a datasource, but then upon `dataBound` event I am setting up each `li` to be a `.kendoTouch` widget to handle some swipes. Every subsequent view navigation results in more "Touch" instances...

Comment: Strangely, looking through the Kendo source, I can't seem to find anywhere that the ListView cleans up its elements before replacing them. That worries me a little.. but, you can subscribe to the `"databinding"` event and do cleanup of the elements there. You actually might just be able to do: `kendo.destroy( $("#listView").data("kendoListView").items() );`

Comment: Yeah, that's a little disconcerting... I like your idea of the `Databinding` event. I will try that and see.

Comment: This is weird... I find that If I call `.destroy` on the `li` directly from the view's `hide` event, then it keeps not only that element (li) but also it's child widgets.

Comment: I think I just discovered that the Kendo UI Console tool is not updating/refreshing properly. If I close my dev console and reopen it, I get different results post `.destroy`, so I think the `kendo.destroy()` is working.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at the documentation , there is really no need of garbage cleanup , if you have so many widgets hmm maybe .Do

```
 kendo.destroy(document.body); // this will destroy all the widgets on page. if not select the widget and call destroy.
```

Documentation : http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/widgets/destroy#destroy-kendo-ui-widgets